# Onclick Image-Selection

Tags: android, picturebox, buttonclick, picturegallery

I'd like to create a Button, on which i can tip, afterwards, there should show up a picture selection which should be scrollable (probably its a grindview idk). It's like the thing in whatsapp on the upper side right, exactly something like that I'd like to do.

How can I do this? What do I need for that in my Layoutfile, and is it possible to set the content of it, to my Database?

[image: Here you see how it should look like.]

I'd like to have something like that 2 but how can I create that. What do I need for it?

Thx In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi safari in that case You need to take Linear layout with horizontal orientation. which having other two Lenear layout like this.

```
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"  >

     <LinearLayout >
            <GridView > set images of smiley</GridView>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" >

          <Button></Button>
          <Button></Button>
          <Button></Button>
          <Button></Button>
     </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

and then set visibility i.e gone and visible on require place

it may help some what.

Comment: yes, taking lay out dynamically and set them visible and invisible on click